# Why does a native windows button still show as disabled despite removing disabled style?

Tags: vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I am trying to automate the process of entering data on a particular dialog and then submitting the dialog, and the data entry part works fine, but when entering the data automatically the Accept button doesn't end up enabled like it does during manual entry.

As a result I have attempted to enable the button in several ways, but it will not activate.

[image: Picture of the dialog]

I have tried using EnableWindow or sending the WM_ENABLED message with SendMessage, and neither has worked.

Here is the code that gets the button handle and attempts to remove Disabled style (VB.NET using P/INVOKE). I have verified using Spy++ that the following approach removed the WS_DISABLED style, but the button still shows as disabled.

```
Private Shared Sub ProceedWithRebuild(ByVal mWindow As IntPtr)
    Dim proceedButton As IntPtr
    Dim style As Long

    proceedButton = FindWindowEx(mWindow, IntPtr.Zero, Nothing, "&Proceed")

    style = GetWindowLong(proceedButton, WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE)

    style = style And (Not WS_DISABLED)

    SetWindowLong(proceedButton, WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE, CType(style, IntPtr))

    UpdateWindow(mWindow)

    SendMessage(proceedButton, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
    SendMessage(proceedButton, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

    Thread.Sleep(500)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the button enabled in the designer?

Comment: How is the button's supposed to become enabled by the app? You're supposed to emulate that behavior I think.

Comment: I don't have access to the code for the window. 

If you enter data manually, the button is enabled when you tab out of the Company text box, but that doesn't happen when you just set the contents of the text box.

I'm not sure how to programmatically tab out of the company textbox, so I thought I could just enable the button, but I guess not.

Comment: What about 1) selecting the appropriate control and 2) sending a TAB using SendKeys or SendMessage?

Comment: Didn't work. I guess I'll have to keep looking.

Comment: Use the automation interfaces. That's what they're for.

Comment: Why don't you just check if the fields are filled and then enable the button?

Comment: I ended up sending keys to do the process the same way you would do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty common way to get UI state updated is to do so when the application goes idle and has retrieved the last message from the message queue.  It is the way that an MFC program works for example, CWinThread::OnIdle() method.  What's nice about it is that the UI will always reflect the program state without splattering code around that explicitly enables or disables the button.  Actually high odds that this is in fact an MFC program, it looks like one with that statusbar.

This is of course a nemesis to your approach.  You can try to hack the enabled state of that button but it won't have any effect.  The UI state code will disable it right away again.  Even if you do manage to enable it, the program itself is still not in the right state to actually process the button's click.

Nothing you can do but go slower.  Actually update those controls like a human would so that the program thinks it is ready to proceed and will enable the button itself.  Use a UI Automation library to make this less painful.

Answer (score 1):

try this code after your call to `FindWindowEx()`:

```
if (proceedButton != NULL)
    EnableWindow(proceedButton, TRUE);
```